# MYSQLi ordering by first character and splitting results into sections

Tags: php, mysql

I want to format SQL results to list out sql entries by first character (Starting with all numbers together ASC, and then starting with A, then B, then C, etc.).  But I also want to have each character have its own section.

Ex:

```
#

123 Company
21st Century
45th Avenue
99th whatever

A

Aerosmith
Animal
Apple

B

Bat
Binary
Bishop


etc.
```

I'd prefer to do this in one query if possible.  I just have no clue how to set something like this up.

Comment: Check the starting letter in PHP on each iteration.

Comment: can you help with a code example?  I can't figure out how to write this to be effective

Comment: Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how you can iterate over an array and check the first character vs. the previous character. If your SQL is ordering correctly this should be all you need.

```
$last = '';
foreach(array('12', '33 what', '44 more', 'aa', 'ab', 'b', 'c', 'cd', 'd', 'dd') as $words ){
    $current = substr($words, 0, 1);
    if(is_numeric($current)) {
        $current = '#';
    }
    if($current != $last) {
         echo "\n" . strtoupper($current) . "\n\n";
    }
    echo $words . "\n";
    $last = $current;
}
```

Demo: https://eval.in/735196

Comment: Worked perfectly!  Thanks!

Comment: I've got another question taking this to another level. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42180469/how-do-i-combine-numbers-into-one-group