# How do I combine numbers into one group

Tags: php

I have the following code that separates strings into groups based on the starting character.  I am now trying to combine all numbers into one group instead of each starting number getting its own group.  Can someone help because I can't figure out how to modify to make this happen?

```
$last = '';
foreach($brandsArray as $words){
    $current = substr($words, 0, 1);
    if(strtoupper($current) != strtoupper($last)) {
         echo "\n
         <a name=\"". strtoupper($current) ."\"><li class=\"title\">" . strtoupper($current) . "</li></a>\n\n";
    }
    echo '<li>'. $words . "</li>\n";
    $last = $current;
}
```

Example of input:

```
1
121
57 
876
Apple
Apple1
Banana
Banana123
Delta
```

What I want the output to look like

```
**#**
1
121
57 
876

**A**
Apple
Apple1

**B**
Banana
Banana123

**D**
Delta
```

What its currently doing is the following

```
**1**
1
121

**5**
57 

**8**
876

**A**
Apple
Apple1

**B**
Banana
Banana123

**D**
Delta
```

Comment: could you please provide sample example of input and expected output

Comment: `<a name=\"". strtoupper($words) ."\"><li class=\"title\">" . strtoupper($words) . "</li></a>\n\n";
`

Comment: @VeshrajJoshi - Updated to show input, what its doing, and what I want it to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the given input and expected output as per the question above.

```
$brandsArray = array('1', '121', '57', '876', 'Apple', 'Apple1', 'Banana', 'Banana123', 'Delta');
$last = '';
foreach($brandsArray as $words){
    // setting the current value as # if is number
    $current = is_numeric($words)?"#":substr($words, 0, 1);
    if (strtoupper($current) != strtoupper($last)) {
         echo "\n
         <a name=\"". strtoupper($current) ."\"><li class=\"title\">" . strtoupper($current) . "</li></a>\n\n";
    }
    echo '<li>'. $words . "</li>\n";
    $last = $current;
}
```